# How to remove the outliers located outside the predication bound in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, confidence-interval, outliers

Hey guys I have one question related to processing of Time series, I have xy data and want to remove the outliers, so i defined it by ones that located outside the the prediction bound, I applied the regress functions [B, Bint, R, Rint, stats] = regress(y, x);but iam confused how to remove that ones?
any help??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [the docs](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/regress.html)

> [b,bint,r,rint] = regress(y,X) returns an n-by-2 matrix rint of
>   intervals that can be used to diagnose outliers. If the interval
>   rint(i,:) for observation i does not contain zero, the corresponding
>   residual is larger than expected in 95% of new observations,
>   suggesting an outlier.

Therefore, to find the location of outliers in your data, it should be just:

```
n = rint(:,1)>0|rint(:,2)<0;
```

Then you can either remove them, plot them in a different colour, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
I tried this command,but the n=0; no point captured.

Comment: `n` shouldn't be a single value but a logical vector with the same length as your data. What do your `rint` values look like? What is the value of `max(rint(:,1))`?

Comment: yes, n have the same length of data but the values is zeros, meaning no one observations passed the condition, 
max(rint(:,1))     =-2.628171901599862e+01
min(rint(:,1))=    -4.373738276113355e+02
min(rint(:,2))=     1.983066866920183e+01
max(rint(:,2))=     4.309366845822975e+02